# Issue in looping through various subfolders of folder and each files of these subfolders

Tags: vba, excel, loops, directory

I want to access each subfolder of my current folder(number of subfolders in each sub folder may vary) and then want to perform some operations in each excel workbook of all these subfolders.

Below mentioned is the code and code is not throwing compile time error but not working. Kindly help me

```
option explicit
Sub LoopFolders()
    Dim strFolder As String
    Dim strSubFolder As String
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim colSubFolders As New Collection
    Dim varItem As Variant
    Dim wbk As Workbook
    ' Parent folder including trailing backslash
    strFolder = "C:\Users\Yashika Vaish\Desktop\yashika\"
    ' Loop through the subfolders and fill Collection object
    strSubFolder = Dir(strFolder & "*", vbDirectory)
    Do While Not strSubFolder = ""
        Select Case strSubFolder
            Case ".", ".."
                ' Current folder or parent folder - ignore
            Case Else
                ' Add to collection
                colSubFolders.Add Item:=strSubFolder, Key:=strSubFolder
        End Select
        ' On to the next one
        strSubFolder = Dir
    Loop
    ' Loop through the collection
    For Each varItem In colSubFolders
        ' Loop through Excel workbooks in subfolder
        strFile = Dir(strFolder & varItem & "\*.xls*")
        Do While strFile <> ""
            ' Open workbook
            Set wbk = Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strFolder & _
                varItem & "\" & strFile, AddToMRU:=False)
           MsgBox "I am open"

            strFile = Dir
        Loop
    Next varItem
End Sub
```

All the required references in tools settings have already been added in this VBA Project. Kindly help me with this code.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with the files in the subfolder?

Comment: I need to open these files and importing some macros and run those but problem occurs at accessing all the subfolders. Kindly help me with this

Comment: "Not working" is not helpful.  What does the code do versus what is expected?  You should throw in some `Debug.Print` calls to figure out what directories are being found vs. what should be found.  There is no obvious reason the above code won't work.  I assume you're only going one level deep?  The code above is not recursive for arbitrary depth.  Typically issues with searching for files/folders come down to missing path separators or searching the wrong directory once the code is verified.

Answer (score 2):

The method below writes the file names from the subfolders too to the workbook. So it finds them.

```
Sub Program()
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 1
    listFiles "D:\Folder 1", i
End Sub

Sub listFiles(ByVal sPath As String, ByRef i As Integer)
    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files

    If (oFiles.Count > 0) Then
        ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
        For Each oFile In oFiles
            Cells(i, "A").Value = oFile.Name
            Cells(i, "B").Value = oFile.Path
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If

    listFolders sPath, i
End Sub

Sub listFolders(ByVal sPath As String, ByRef i As Integer)
    Dim vaArray     As Variant
    Dim oFile       As Object
    Dim oFSO        As Object
    Dim oFolder     As Object
    Dim oFiles      As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.subfolders

    If (oFiles.Count > 0) Then
        ReDim vaArray(1 To oFiles.Count)
        For Each oFile In oFiles
            listFiles oFile.Path, i
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much but this code is not working and give me run time error 28 "Out of Range Subscript" my purpose is to get through all the subfolders of a folder, kindly help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use & it's a #WorksAtMyBox certified code ;)

```
Option Explicit
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoMainDirectory As Scripting.folder
Dim fsoSubfolder As Scripting.folder
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.file
Dim strFilePath
Dim filecounter As Long
Dim foldercounter As Long


Public Sub FileFinder(fileorfolder As String)

    If fso Is Nothing Then
        Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
    End If


    Set fsoMainDirectory = fso.GetFolder(fileorfolder)
    If fsoMainDirectory.SubFolders.Count > 0 Then
        For Each fsoSubfolder In fsoMainDirectory.SubFolders
            foldercounter = foldercounter + 1
            Debug.Print "Folder: " & foldercounter & fsoSubfolder.Path
            FileFinder (fsoSubfolder.Path)
        Next fsoSubfolder
    End If

    If fsoMainDirectory.Files.Count > 0 Then
        For Each fsoFile In fsoMainDirectory.Files
            ProcessFile (fsoFile.Path)
        Next fsoFile
    End If



End Sub

Public Sub ProcessFile(file As String)
    filecounter = filecounter + 1
    Debug.Print "File: " & filecounter & ": " & file
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I search through a folder looking for a specific file type. (early binding is your friend at this point in development). Make sure you have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime reference enabled.

```
Option Explicit
Sub test()
Dim fso As Scripting.FileSystemObject
Dim fsoMainDirectory As Scripting.Folder
Dim fsoSubfolder As Scripting.Folder
Dim fsoFile As Scripting.File
Dim strFilePath

Set fso = New Scripting.FileSystemObject
Set fsoMainDirectory = fso.GetFolder("Directory, with trailing \")

For Each fsoFile In fsoMainDirectory.Files
    If fsoFile.Type = "Microsoft Excel 97-2003 Worksheet" Then '.xls file type
        strFilePath = fsoFile.Path
        Application.Workbooks.Open strFilePath
    End If
Next fsoFile
End Sub
```

How deep do your sub folders go? Are you the only one will use this macro? Looping through n subfolders with an unknown number of subfolders is doable, but my method involves an array of counters. This array can lower performance, and as such don't want to do that if we don't need to.

Comment: Thank you for sharing but this code is not looping through any sub folders and My purpose is to go through each subfolder of my parent folders and each workbook of y sub folders. Kindly help me with this